# Using ResourceSet to create a file

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, emf

I am new to Java and currently trying to work with `ResourceSet` and `ResourceFactory` from the EMF modelling framework in Eclipse. I have been trying to create a new file with an xml extension in the file system. My code looks something like this:

```
ResourceSet resourceSet =new ResourceSetImpl();
resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("arxml", new XMIResourceImpl());

URI uri =URI.createURI("D:/User/file.xml");
Resource res = resourceSet.createResource(uri);

try{
    resource.save(null);
    java.lang.System.out.println("success");
} catch (IOException e){
    java.lang.System.out.print("no");
}
```

But for some unknown reason I don't see any `file.xml` being created in the file system. I have been trying to solve this issue for a long time, but no result yet. Could somebody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample is completely wrong: URI defines the namespace of the resource within the ecore metadata, not the actual location of a serialized resource. Usually the URI comes from your Ecore model definition. Actually, what you need is to pass an OutputStream to the Resource.save() instead of null. You also need to add some content to your Resource, otherwise the serialized XMI will be empty.

Example:

```
 ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
 resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("arxml", new XMIResourceImpl());

 URI uri = URI.createURI("http://example.myorganization.com/");
 Resource res = resourceSet.createResource(uri);

 // TODO add some content here
 // res.getContents().add(...)

 try{
    resource.save(new FileOutputStream("D:/User/file.xml"));
    java.lang.System.out.println("success");

 } catch (IOException e){
   java.lang.System.out.print("no");
 }
```

This is simply an example. It is expected that you define your Ecore model and generate all the required code to work with your model.

Answer (score 1):

Try your code sample with `URI.createFileURI` to create the URI instead of `URI.createURI`. The URI created will be mapped to a file. I'm almost sure the XML extension is associated to a `XMLResourceImpl` automatically so it should be in XML format.

Also, you registered a `XMIResourceImpl` with the `arxml` extension, but your file extension is `xml` so you will not use your registered resource (basically, the mapping you expressed is useless in your snippet). If you want XMI instead of XML, change your file extension or overwrite the registered XML extension or register `*` as file extension (which map all extensions to `XMIResourceImpl`.